# How can I select the primary key columns from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to select the columns which is the primary key or the column which is not null. How can I do that?

And I want only the columns, not the values.

Comment: What do you mean by you only want the columns but not the values?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Can you show the table and sample values from which you need to pick primary key column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next answer is more apropriate, I'm not sure how to transfer accepted answer.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<TABLE_NAME>' and IS_NULLABLE = 'NO'
```

Comment: A not null column is not necessarily a primary key

Comment: Primary Keys can not be NULL though and the question ask for PK's or not null's.

Answer (score 14):

To list the primary key columns, you can try this query:

```
SELECT
    kc.name,
    c.NAME
FROM 
    sys.key_constraints kc
INNER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON kc.parent_object_id = ic.object_id  and kc.unique_index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
WHERE
    kc.type = 'PK'
```

and to list the foreign keys, use the following:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 'Parent table',
    c.NAME 'Parent column name',
    OBJECT_NAME(referenced_object_id) 'Referenced table',
    cref.NAME 'Referenced column name'
FROM 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c 
       ON fkc.parent_column_id = c.column_id 
          AND fkc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cref 
       ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id 
          AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure the primary key query is correct - its returning extra non-PrimaryKey fields in my test database.

Comment: @ Peter kelly this query retrieves all the columns with or without constraints.

Comment: The Foreign Key query works brilliantly but, as pointed out by PeterKelly and Craig, the Primary Key query lists *all other indices* on the table – in addition to the primary key constraint.

Comment: Suggested Edit should fix the issue of showing all keys. should only show PKs now

Answer (score 4):

### List Primary Key Columns

To list the Primary Key columns, I used SQL Server’s implementation of the ANSI standard [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) as they’re easier to work with: there’s no need to use the `object_name()` function to translate `object_id`s to human-readable names.

I use `[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE]` to list the
constraints on a table – both primary and foreign keys;
`[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE` has similar information but
lacks the `ORDINAL_POSITION`.

`[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLE_CONSTRAINTS]` provides extra information on the
constraints (most importantly the `CONSTRAINT_TYPE`) but doesn’t list the columns that the constraint applies to.

To get the only the list of columns used by the primary key, join the above
two tables using the name of the constraint:

```
SELECT
     tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,tc.TABLE_NAME
    ,tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    ,kcu.COLUMN_NAME
    ,kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc

INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu
    ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME

WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND tc.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a built-in System View called INFORMATION_KEY_COLUMN_USAGE to get the primary key columns

```
SELECT [COLUMN_NAME]
FROM [DatabaseName].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[KEY_COLUMN_USAGE]
WHERE [TABLE_NAME] = 'TableName'
```

Comment: once again it brings back FK and IX columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<your_table>' and COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI'
```

this example is tested on mariadb, mysql. 
Might work on others but depends on information_schema details.

Answer (score 0):

using only the `sys.*` tables:

```
select
    t.name,
    kc.type,
    kc.name,
    c.name,
    i.is_unique,
    i.is_primary_key,
    i.is_unique_constraint,
    ic.is_descending_key,
    ic.key_ordinal,
    ic.is_included_column
from sys.key_constraints kc
inner join sys.objects t on t.object_id = kc.parent_object_id
inner join sys.indexes i on i.name = kc.name
inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.object_id = kc.parent_object_id and ic.index_id = i.index_id
inner join sys.columns c on c.object_id = kc.parent_object_id and c.column_id = ic.column_id
order by
    t.name,
    kc.type,
    kc.name,
    ic.key_ordinal
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself after all:

```
select sc.name from sys.objects as so
inner join sys.indexes as si        on so.object_id = si.object_id 
                                    and si.is_primary_key = 1
inner join sys.index_columns as ic  on si.object_id = ic.object_id
                                    and si.index_id = ic.index_id
inner join sys.columns as sc            on so.object_id = sc.object_id
                                    and ic.column_id = sc.column_id
where so.object_id = object_id('TABLE_NAME')
```