# sp_columns order by primary key column

Tags: sql-server

`exec sp_columns 'table'` returns all column names in `COLUMN_NAMES` column:

```
TABLE_QUALIFIER     TABLE_OWNER     TABLE_NAME          COLUMN_NAME             DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME       PRECISION   LENGTH  SCALE   RADIX   NULLABLE    REMARKS     COLUMN_DEF  SQL_DATA_TYPE   SQL_DATETIME_SUB    CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH   ORDINAL_POSITION    IS_NULLABLE SS_DATA_TYPE
transdata           dbo             Flow                Distance                6           float           15          8       NULL    10      1           NULL        NULL        6               NULL                NULL                9                   YES         109
transdata           dbo             Flow                FlowID                  4           int identity    10          4       0       10      0           NULL        NULL        4               NULL                NULL                10                  NO          56
```

What I want is the `COLUMN_NAMES` to show primary key column(s) first, followed by non-primary key columns. Is this even possible with `sp_columns`?

Ordering by primary key should fix this but `sp_columns` doesn't return primary key info.

```
TABLE_QUALIFIER     TABLE_OWNER     TABLE_NAME          COLUMN_NAME             DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME       PRECISION   LENGTH  SCALE   RADIX   NULLABLE    REMARKS     COLUMN_DEF  SQL_DATA_TYPE   SQL_DATETIME_SUB    CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH   ORDINAL_POSITION    IS_NULLABLE SS_DATA_TYPE
transdata           dbo             Flow                FlowID                  4           int identity    10          4       0       10      0           NULL        NULL        4               NULL                NULL                10                  NO          56
transdata           dbo             Flow                Distance                6           float           15          8       NULL    10      1           NULL        NULL        6               NULL                NULL                9                   YES         109
```

Comment: You can create a temporary table and save the result there using INSERT..EXEC.. Then sort the result any way you want

Comment: Alternatively, you can use sp_help instead of sp_columns. If it shows more than you want just take its code and use only a part of it making up your own procedure that will return only what you want in order you want

Comment: The **primary key** is a property of the **table** - not any specific column ... so this information is *not* available if you look at only the columns

Comment: Feel free to suggest any other better way, I just want all column names in table ordered by primary key columns first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is too complicated to simple exec a SP.
You should write query yourself (`IC` columns is null if column not a PK):

```
SELECT 
    TableName   = OBJECT_NAME(C.object_id), 
    ColumnName  = C.name,
    ColumnType  = TYPE_NAME(C.system_type_Id), 
    IsPK        = IIF(IC.object_id IS NULL, 0, 1)
FROM sys.columns                C
LEFT JOIN sys.key_constraints   KC  ON KC.parent_object_id = C.object_id AND kc.type = 'PK'
LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns     IC  ON KC.parent_object_id = IC.object_id  AND KC.unique_index_id = IC.index_id AND IC.column_id = C.column_id
WHERE C.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
ORDER BY ...
```

Here is similar question: [How can I select the primary key columns from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153108/how-can-i-select-the-primary-key-columns-from-a-table)

Comment: I just want columns names in my table. where is table name filter?

Comment: ORDER BY ... ?? Order by IsPK returns non-primary key columns first.

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY IsPK DESC, C.column_id` to reverse sort order